# Multiple chi square tests between sub-groups

Tags: r, chi-squared

New to R.  I have constructed a frequency table but wish to perform chi square tests on each of the sub-groups to get something that looks like this in R:

```
            Red     Yellow   Green       p value
Location                
L1          4000    1223     11          xx
L2          3300    109      25          xx
L3          3000    120      15          xx
```

I've used the code below, which gives me an overall p value but more interested in comparing each location individual between the colours e.g. L1 in Red vs Yellow vs Green, L2 in Red vs Yellow vs Green etc.

```
CDtable_loc <- meta_CD %>%
  select(colour,location) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = colour,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 1,
    type = all_categorical() ~ "categorical",
    missing_text = "Missing") %>%
    add_p()
```

Would be grateful for your help!

Comment: You can test each row separately with `chisq.test()` but the default null hypothesis is that the number of observations in each color is equal which is so clearly false that no test is necessary. You can also use the `p=` argument to test the row against a different null hypothesis, eg `p=c(.75, .23, .02)` but you would need data independent of the observed frequency table to get those values.